# What is & doing in a rust for in loop?

Tags: rust

Trying to understand how `&` works in a rust `for..in` loop...
For example let's say we have something simple like a find largest value function which takes a slice of `i32`'s and returns the largest value.

```rust
fn largest(list: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut largest = list[0];

    for item in list {
        if *item > largest {
            largest = *item;
        }
    }

    largest
}
```

In the scenario given above `item` will be an `&i32` which makes sense to me. We borrow a slice of `i32`'s and as a result the `item` would also be a reference to the individual item in the slice. At this point we can dereference the value of `item` with `*` which is what I assume how a pointer based language would work.

But now if we alter this slightly below...

```rust
fn largest(list: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let mut largest = list[0];

    for &item in list {
        if item > largest {
            largest = item;
        }
    }

    largest
}
```

If we put an `&` in front of `item` this changes `item` within the `for..in` into an `i32`... Why? In my mind this is completely counterintuitive to how I would have imagined it to work. This to me says, "Give me an address/reference to `item`"... Which in itself would already be a reference. So then how does `item` get dereferenced? Is this just a quirk with rust or am I fundamentally missing something here.

Comment: It's a pattern.  The iterator yelds `&i32` values, so you do a pattern matching to get `i32` instead of `&i32`

Answer (score 7):

All variable assignments in Rust, including loop variables in `for` loops and function arguments, are assigned using *pattern matching*. The value that is being assigned is matched against the target pattern, and Rust tries to fill in the "blanks", i.e. the target variable names, in a way that substituting the values makes the pattern match the value. Let's look at a few examples.

```
let x = 5;
```

This is the simplest case. Obvious, substituting `x` with `5` makes both sides match.

```
if let Some(x) = Some(5) {}
```

Here, `x` will also become `5`, since substituting that value into the pattern will make both side identical.

```
let &x = &5;
```

Again, the two sides match when setting `x` to `5`.

```
if let (Some(&x), &Some(y)) = (Some(&5), &Some(6)) {}
```

This assignment results in `x = 5` and `y = 6`, since substituting these values into the pattern makes both sides match.

Let's apply this to your `for` loop. In each loop iteration, the pattern after `for` is matched against the next value returned by the iterator. We are iterating an `&[i32]`, and [the item type of the resulting iterator is `&i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#associatedtype.Item), so the iterator yields a `&i32` in each iteration. This reference is matched against the pattern `&item`. Applying what we have seen above, this means `item` becomes an `i32`.

Note that assigning a value of a type that does not have the `Copy` marker trait will *move* that value into the new variable. All examples above use integers, which are `Copy`, so the value is copied instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic here, pure logic. Consider this example:

```
let a = 1;
let b = &a;  // b is a reference to a
let &c = &a; // c is a copy of value a
```

You can read the third line of the example above as "Assign reference to a to a reference to c". This basically creates a virtual variable "reference to c", assigns to it the value `&a` and then dereferences it to get the value of `c`.

```
let a = 1;
let ref_c = &a;
let c = *ref_c;

// If you try to go backwards into this assignments, you get:
let &c = &a;
let &(*ref_c) = &a;
let ref_c = &a; // which is exactly what it was
```

The same occurs with the `for .. in` syntax. You iterate over `item_ref`, but assign them to `&item`, which means that the type of `item` is `Item`.

```
for item_ref in list {
  let item = *item_ref;
  ...
}

// we see that item_ref == &item, so above is same as
for &item in list {
  ...
}
```